# Maximal Ideals of Algebras of Finite Type over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I want to show that every maximal ideal of a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of finite type $A$ is the kernel of a homomorphism $A\to \mathbb{C}$.

Via the Nullstellensatz, this becomes fairly simple. Is there a way of doing it without using the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: It is also fairly simple to prove the Nullstellensatz from this statement, so in that sense, *no*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice trick over $\mathbb{C}$, but some people might find it unsatisfactory:

Given any $\mathbb{C}$ algebra $A$, then a maximal ideal of $A$ is the kernel of a surjective map $A \to k$ for some field $k$ extending $\mathbb{C}$.

Now suppose $x \in k - \mathbb{C}$, since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically complete $x$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$.  This means that the elements $\frac{1}{x-\lambda}$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ are all linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$, as a linear dependency would give a polynomial expression for $x$.

So we see any field extension of $\mathbb{C}$ must have uncountable dimension over $\mathbb{C}$, but a finitely generated algebra will have countable dimension. So the quotient of a finitely generated algebra by any maximal ideal must just be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Do you have a reference / proof for the maximal ideal being the kernel of a surjective map into a field extension of $\mathbb{C} $?

Comment: @fish_monster An ideal $\mathfrak m \subset A$ is maximal if and only if $k = A / \mathfrak m$ is a field. The composition $\mathbb C \subset A \to k$ then shows that $k$ is a field extension of $\mathbb C$.